# Lost on how to validate a form post with ASP.NET MVC 3.0 / Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

A very simple scenario, I have a page with a form, I want to submit it to the server and if data is successfully validated display different stuff/data/page (I don't care if the URL changes or stays the same). What is the best way to do it?

Some more data - I need a wizard type UI and it needs to work with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: for the first part of the question, use `data annotations`. Google about them to know more. and please, post what all you have tried and ask only the problems you have encountered in doing that. Such a generic question is very difficult to answer. Read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and Welcome to `STACK OVERFLOW`

Comment: Posting data to the server is among the most basic functions of MVC, suggest you have a look at the MVC videos at asp.net/mvc for some initial training

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check the ModelState.isvalid property. If all the data passes validation, it will return true, otherwise false.
In your controller

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SomeAction (SomeModel viewModel)
 {
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
   //display different stuff/data/page
  }
  else
  {
   return View(viewModel);
  }
 }
```